# Enviando variable con cadena html por ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo una variable que contiene una plantilla que debo guardar en una base de datos:

```
var plantilla = "<div>Esto es HTML</div>";


 $.ajax({ url: '../Guardar', method: 'POST', dataType: "html", data: { _plantilla: plantilla} })
```

Siempre da error 500.

Si le elimino los `<div>`,  se envía sin problemas.

He probado cambiando el dataType, sin éxito.

Comment: Por un lado estás enviando un `dataType` incorrecto, sería `json`. Por otro lado, el error 500 te lo está dando el código que corre en el servidor web, indicando que ha fallado por algún motivo. Necesitas compartir el código que ejecutas en el servidor para recibir esos datos, ya que es el culpable del error 500, y no el código javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución podria ser usando

```
JSON.stringify({ _plantilla: plantilla})
```

En el data del request